# Unable to call python Function in Webkit report Openerp

Tags: python, webkit, odoo, openerp-7

My report file contains

```
class AccountInvoice_Report(report_sxw.rml_parse):

    def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context):

        super(AccountInvoice_Report, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)

        self.localcontext.update({

        'time': time,
        'cr':cr,
        'uid': uid,
        'get_address': self.get_address,
    })
```

and  I have written get_address function. when i call that function in my mako file as

```
    <% get_address() %>
```

Then it gives Error as

```
   File "memory:0xb23c67ccL", line 208, in render_body
   <% get_address()%>
   TypeError: 'Undefined' object is not callable
```

What mistake I am doing file defining or calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

**my_parser.py**

```
import time
from openerp.report import report_sxw

class AccountInvoice_Report(report_sxw.rml_parse):

    def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context):
        super(AccountInvoice_Report, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)
        self.localcontext.update({
                                  'time': time,
                                  'cr':cr,
                                  'uid': uid,
                                  'get_address': self.get_address,})
    def get_address(self):
        #your code
        return 'address'

report_sxw.report_sxw('report.your_report_name', 'model', 'path/to/mako', parser=AccountInvoice_Report)
```

Include this parser in `__init__.py`

```
import my_parser
```

also don't forget to import your report folder in main `__init__.py`

Comment: That's the basic thing. I have included it. If I haven't then Error will be different. Please check the Error.

Comment: the error will be same if you don't import the folder.I faced same issue before as i forgot to include it. Did you check your custom parser is getting called, put a breakpoint and check.

Comment: AccountInvoice_Report is your parser class, did you write something like this? `report_sxw.report_sxw('report.your_report_name', 'model', 'path/to/mako', parser=AccountInvoice_Report)`

Comment: i mean check whether your parser class is being called, can you access cr,time,uid from your mako?

Answer (score 0):

Also try to restart your IDE/server. It works for me. Sometimes you can have many instances running the same time.

Answer (score 0):

On:

```
report_sxw.report_sxw('report.your_report_name', 'model', 'path/to/mako', parser=AccountInvoice_Report)
```

You should ensure your '**your_report_name**' is identical to the field 'report_name' on the model 'ir.actions.report.xml' (where you configure your report).

The function report_sxw.report_sxw() can't find the 'report_name' of the report to link the parser.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but maybe someone can make use of this. I have used the approach you are trying to do, and the following code worked for me on 6.0:
On your **init** instead of

`'get_address': self.get_address,})`

I used:

`'get_address': self.get_address(),})`

Then I declared my method as:

`def get_address(self):`

Finally on my mako i called it with:

`${get_address}`

Note that on the mako file I'm not using 'get_address()' because it sent me an error saying that the string get_address is not a callable object. Hope it helps.